# unable to verify etherscan contract may be due to high optimize runs

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, etherscan, contract-verification

I have used high optimize runs as 999999999 while deploying contract..
I need to verify contract on etherscan but it has range from 0-1000000 ..
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to verify using truffle. Take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/quick-programming/verify-a-smart-contract-on-etherscan-using-truffle-cb2656fd9c41).
Remember to change settings as required in `truffle-config.js` file.
Note: command to run for already deployd contract `truffle run verify SimpleStorage@0x61C9157A9EfCaf6022243fA65Ef4666ECc9FD3D7 --network mainnet`
[image]

Comment: but truffle is  using etherscan API....i have tried etherscan api plugin in REMIX and other platform...etherscan api has also limits for optimization runs as 0 to 1000000

Comment: in truffle config you can put runs as required. To verify in etherscan of course you have to use etherscan api, verification of contract is not done in blockchain.